Can't test ZIO HTTP client with exponential retry by advancing TestClock
I'm using ZIO HTTP 3.0.0-RC6 (transitively pulls ZIO 2.0.21, but I evict it manually by specifying ZIO version), ZIO and ZIO-test 2.1-RC1 with Scala 2.13. My suite looks like this (the point of the second test is to test retry, so there is nothing listening on 127.0.0.1:80):
  object IpGetterSpec extends ZIOSpecDefault {
    val schedule = Schedule.exponential(10.milliseconds) && 
        Schedule.recurs(2).tapOutput(o => ZIO.logInfo(s"retrying $o"))
    def spec = suite("IpGetterSpec")(
      test("test retry exponential") {
        for {
          fiber <- ZIO.fail("fail").retry(schedule).fork
          _ <- TestClock.adjust(100.milliseconds)
          res <- fiber.join.exit
        } yield assertTrue(res.isFailure)
      },
      test("request fails after being tried three times") {
        for {
          client <- ZIO.service[Client]
          fiber  <- client.url(URL.decode("http://127.0.0.1:80/?format=json").toOption.get).get("/").retry(schedule).fork
          _ <- TestClock.adjust(100.milliseconds)
          res <- fiber.join.exit
        } yield assertTrue(res.isFailure)
      }
    ).provideShared(Client.default, Scope.default)
  }

The first test runs, the second one hangs indefinitely. Interestingly enough, if I rewrite the second test with live clock, like so:
  test("request fails after being tried three times") {
    for {
      client <- ZIO.service[Client]
      res  <- client.url(URL.decode("http://127.0.0.1:80/?format=json").toOption.get).get("/").retry(schedule).exit
    } yield assertTrue(res.isFailure)
  } @@ TestAspect.withLiveClock

it works.
Question: does this have something to do with ZIO HTTP client? Is this a known issue?

You are using the live client, does that mean this test is talking to an actual server?

@paulpdaniels it's trying to, but because the server is not listening, it fails to.

The issue is that, while the test is using a fake clock, the ZClient.live is interacting with the network driver on the host system (via a Netty interface). This interaction takes time and is inherently async from the application perspective. When you call get(url).retry(schedule).fork you are telling ZIO to run that operation + all subsequent retries on a separate fork, then in the next line you are telling the test to skip time, but most likely the socket hasn't even connected at that point let alone started a retry cycle. Then you wait for the fiber to finish with the join effectively blocking the current fiber.
This is the reason that it hangs. The application call fails, but you have already jumped time so the retries which are waiting for a time progression are instead just stuck (An easy check to verify this would be to switch to a schedule that doesn't have any time dependency, like recurs).
In order to address this you could:

Use the live clock, as you saw this unblocks it because it doesn't get deadlocked waiting for the clock to progress. Whether you use this depends on what you are testing, I wouldn't suggest using long retry cycles since that will increase your test time
Consider whether you can just use the TestClient instead, in most cases TestClock is not going to play well with things that need to interact with real world systems like networks because you can't effectively mock time in the real world.
Use a non-time dependent schedule. This would be somewhat brittle, but it would at least verify that retries are working and the application behaves correctly even if you can't test with time involved.
Remove this test? I'm assuming this is just a minimized example to show the issue you are facing, but if not, I would question the need to verify that the ZClient is working, and consider just not having this test at all since it is just testing third party code.


Okay, but when I stick this test without changes into zio-http-testkit subproject of zio-http, it works with TestClock. How would you explain that?

@Yar Are you by chance sticking it into the TestClientSpec?

no, it's in a separate file next to it.

Not sure if this is should be a comment or an answer, but your tests works fine when I pasted them into the zio-http project. Could be an issue with your versions.
As a side note, when an effect has a scope, you should define the start and end of that scope using ZIO.scoped.
for {
      client <- ZIO.service[Client]
      res <- ZIO.scoped(client.url(???).get("/")) // this effect has a scope
} yield assertTrue(res.isFailure)

How much you want to wrap with ZIO.scoped of course depends on your scenario. If you acquired a db connection from your db pool, you probably want to do something with it, like making a query, before finalizing the db connection.
https://zio.dev/reference/resource/scope/

I tried sticking my tests into zio-http project and it worked for me as well. However, after trying the same zio version in my project, they still hang. So I still don't know what the problem is and which difference between zio-http and my setup causes the test to run in the former but not the latter.

Did you try with the same version for both zio and zio-test? Could also try the latest RC for both if you want to experiment with 2.1

Yes, I set zio and zio-test version to 2.0.21 then to 2.0.22, no luck

I would try asking in the ZIO discord. You can find the invite link in the footer on ZIO documentation (http://zio.dev)
